# removing the search and other icons from terminal window

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, i3-wm

I have been trying to customize my terminal with Ubuntu and wanted to remove the search button and some other buttons in the terminal window shown here:

[image]

as you can see the search bar in the upper right corner, the three lines button in the upper right corner and the add terminal button in the top left corner if someone would know how to remove these it would be appreciated...

Thanks :)

Comment: What terminal program and version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all buttons by reverting to a "legacy" title bar, i.e., a title bar provided by the window manager. You can change the relevant settings with the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar false
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings default-show-menubar false
```

The first command disables the client side decorations, whereas the second command hides the menu bar.